# how to access the Origin XY and size Width Heigh of a container ScrollView given their Children UIViews

Tags: objective-c, uiview, scrollview, cgpoint, cgrectmake

I the storybook, there is a main UIViewController of type ScrollView, it includes several UIViews. In the code I have an NSArray that contains all the UIViews that are withinvthe scrollView.
for some reason, the width, height ,x and y of the scrollView are required to introduce some adjustments on the UIVIews.
The question is, how can I have access or how to get the Origin X,Y and size(width and height) of the scrollView “the mainUIView container”.

Note:_ the NSArray contains only UIViews as children of the ScrollView.

Comment: what about using some property like .parentViewController?

Comment: After reasearching...I found a method called .superview

Comment: Do u think .superview is like or similar to the one you provided

Comment: Superview is a view that contains the current view. And parentView is another view controller that may be containing the view controller inside a container view